# Why does this graphic look different on Mobile vs Desktop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, pdf

I have this graphic that has rays coming out of the circle in the upper left-hand corner, and a clipping mask is used to cut it off where I'd like the rays to end.

The vector file and PDF look fine on a desktop, but the person who received this file says that the rays were distorted when they opened it — which (I think) is due to the fact that the PDF was opened up by that person on their phone through a Google Drive (app) preview.

The PNG looks fine on all devices, regardless of whether it's previewed the Google Drive mobile app or on a desktop, but the PDF is what that person is having problems with, and I'm not sure why.

Could it just be that the Google Drive mobile app can't correctly preview the rays, and they need to download the PDF to a PC to see the correct/undistorted graphic? Or should I be saving the file differently to get it to preview correctly on G Drive's mobile app preview?

This is how it's supposed to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo6kg.jpg

This is how it looks on mobile:

[image: How it looks on mobile]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend not to use masks in a final version (It's OK for a working file that is subject to change, and where you want to keep the flexibility).

Use Pathfinder to chop off the invisible parts to get a clean version, then these problems can't occur.

Comment: Great information to know going forward. I used the Pathfinder tool as you said and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are delivering a file to your client, remember to always **expand your strokes,** **create outlines from text** and (as AAGD mentioned) **use Pathfinder** give the final form before you send them out.

Always keep a backup of the original work for further modifications of requested or future jobs but if you are required to deliver a vector file, remember to do all of the above.